# android.useAndroidX property is not enabled, why it should be?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, androidx

I am having an issue with androiDx libraries, so when I am adding shimmer library into my projects or glide photo library or when i update the google play services ads to 19.1.0 it keeps asking me to enable android dx

> ERROR: This project uses AndroidX dependencies, but the 'android.useAndroidX' property is not enabled. Set this property to true in the gradle.properties file and retry.
>   The following AndroidX dependencies are detected: androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.1

but I don't want to enable it, or is it a must?

this is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "folo.new.test.my"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.3'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
}
```

Comment: did you find the solution to this??

Answer (score 4):

Add `android.useAndroidX=true` in to `gradle.properties` file .

I found solution from this [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Answer (score 2):

add this line of code into your gradel.properties file.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
```

if you add androidX dependencies, it will work only when you set its property to true otherwise it will not working.